# Flutter on tap barrier

Tags: flutter

I am using `showModalBottomSheet` to open a bottom sheet and set `isDismissible` to `false` to disable dismissing the bottom sheet on tapping the barrier

I need to detect when the user tap on the barrier to run a logical code, how can I detect tapping on barrier?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: it's nothing special see example of https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

Comment: Do you want to close your bottomSheet with a close button?

Comment: I want to count the number of tapping in the barrier, And run a code in the users tapped on barriers 10 times in less than two seconds, it's a hidden feature :-)